# What could cause a microcontroller on a board not to accept programming?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, avr, avrdude, icsp

**EDIT: To summarise - when I take the microcontroller off the board, it works. But when I leave it on the board and try to program it, I cannot.**

I have designed a PCB and had it fabricated. This PCB has ICSP programming pins specifically for the purpose of allowing it to be reprogrammed in-situ.

**My problem is that the chip** ([ATtiny44A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc8183.pdf)) **will not accept new programming** - indeed, the programmer hardware doesn't even detect its presence! - unless I remove it from the board and place it into a ZIF socket.

When I try to program the chip on the board (using a clone [USBasp](https://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) and [avrdude](https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/)), it says "target didn't answer" and such - in other words, no chip found. Very occasionally it works (like, one time in fifty), but reports verification errors and the like.

I have tested that the ICSP pins are connected to the correct pins of the chip using a multimeter; and also checked for shorts between the pins.

I have partially assembled the board. I realise that ICSP can often be negatively affected by the presence of other connected circuitry; but I have not yet placed any components that should cause a problem.

Here is the schematic. I have greyed out parts that are not yet present on the board. As you can see, nothing has been connected to the microcontroller by more than one wire, and therefore does not exist:

[image: schematic]

Here are some pictures of the board. The enamelled wire is present because I damaged a trace on the board whilst soldering. Two of the resistors underneath the chip are only connected at one end, in an attempt to diagnose the problem.

[image: top of board]

[image: bottom of board]

I've tried everything I can think of. What could be causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: I'm sure I entirely follow. So I'll try and summarize what I think I read. "If you pull the MCU out of your board and use it in a professional programmer, the device 'just works right' every time. But if you try a a variety of methods for in-circuit programming on your own board, it rarely works at all. And in the few cases where it seems to start working, in the end it has errors and doesn't work. So 100% failure, when on your board." Is that a good summary?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. I've made other boards with ICSP headers, and they've worked perfectly. It's just *this* board that is being insane. Also, when you say "use it in a professional programmer", I'm just using the same USBasp programmer. The only difference is that I'm taking the chip off the board first.

Comment: I didn't find a pull-up on the Tiny44 Reset line. While that pin can be used for other purposes, if you want to use ISP it will need a pull-up resistor on it.

Comment: Decoupling Caps?

Comment: Is C1 the only bypass cap on the whole board, or are the bypass caps for the microprocessor not shown on your schematic?

Comment: @Wendall Doesn't the USBasp provide that pullup though? I could understand it needing a pullup for normal usage, but....for programming? C1 is the decoupling cap for the tiny44, and is located right below the chip. Perhaps I ought to have decoupling for the other chips, but that'd be a separate issue. (I also realise that the presence of the MCP23017 chips would probably cause issues with ICSP - i.e. I have made mistakes in the design - but again this would be a separate issue.)

Comment: Why has someone voted to close the question? Own up! There is nothing wrong with my question. I put a lot of effort into it, and provided schematics and everything. What reason could you possibly have for voting to close it?

Comment: No-one has downvoted your question. It currently has no votes either way. The 1 close vote it has is "too broad" - not sure why though.

Comment: @brhans It says "share  edit  close (1)  delete  flag". One cowardly person has voted to close it, without even having the common decency to say why. EDIT: I don't see this "too broad" reason at my end. But in any event, how the hell can it be too broad? It's highly specific.

Comment: Having a rant about votes is a surefire way to attract downvotes though ...

Comment: And voting to close my question for no good reason is a surefire way to attract complaints from the OP. How else am I supposed to react? I don't even know who did it. All I'm trying to do here is get some help.

Comment: @Wendall I have just tried adding a 10K pullup on the reset line; and have also tried adding a 3.3µF capacitor to the power rails. No joy.

Comment: I think you have pretty much verified that there is a difference between your "programmer" and your layout. If you can use an oscilloscope and program one in your programmer, watch the ICSP lines especially the rising and falling edges of them and also the Reset line. Then do the same while trying the one on your board. You will find the difference, and find the problem.

Comment: Are you providing power and ground from your ICSP plug/jack, or from an "on board" supply? Both the programmer and the ATtiny must have the same ground refference. (just a thought)

Comment: SW2 is open when attempting to program?  The board is powered separately from the programmer?  Have you used an ohm meter to verify connections between the chip and the ISP header?  Can you scope the MISO and MOSI lines while attempting to program?

Comment: Is the red mark on your ISP header to denote pin1?  If so, that doesn't look right.

Comment: Users with [sufficient reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=all) can cast close votes. It isn't required (just encouraged) to leave a comment explaining such votes. The system will automatically add a comment for certain types of votes, such as those for duplicates. SE is community-moderated so you'll often see differences of opinion, but generally moderation actions require a minimum number of votes to take effect. Don't lose your cool about a single vote. The question _could_ be very broad with many possible causes, however I think you formulated it well.

Comment: SW2 is actually absent from the board. Power is being applied from the programmer; although I also tried applying it externally. I used the continuity function of my meter to check the connections. I will try to scope the lines. The red mark denotes VCC ;)

Answer (score 1):

For debugging, I would put the uC on a breadboard, and one-by-one connect its pins to the target board and see which connection blocks the programming.

As I see no connection on your board to the logic pins involved in programming, my guess would be the power pin, because either:

- the the board loads the power beyond what the programmer can supply
- the programmer power-cycles the uC which is prevent by the board

In both cases a suitable resistors between the uC power / ICSp and the rest of the board might solve the problem. Try 100 Ohm for a start.

Comment: There is nothing else on the board to draw power; and also nothing on the board to prevent power cycling. If I power the chip directly from the programmer via the ICSP header, the board should have no influence on it. I will try your suggestion of connecting the pins one-by-one and seeing when the problem starts. That's a good idea. I will try it on another copy of the board to begin with, to avoid having to remove this chip again, but if I get no errors I will desolder the chip and run the tests again.